# I need to unbold other attributes through JS

Tags: javascript, html

Good afternoon, I'm an intern (Brazilian) and I'm developing a text editor for internal emails at the company, I managed to come up with a way to put bold and attributes but I can't remove them, my code below

```
function enableBold() {
const selection = window.getSelection();
if (selection.rangeCount) {
  const wrapper = document.createElement('b');
  const range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
  range.surroundContents(wrapper);
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}
```

}

Comment: You say "I can't". Why not? Is there an error? What is the actual vs expected result?

Answer (score -1):

use execcomand, it's easier, this way you're doing it is a lot of work
An example

```
document.execCommand("bold");
```

Comment: `execCommand()` is deprecated and not recommended. [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

Comment: Hi Mykaf, how would you solve the problem?

Comment: execCommand is deprecated that's true, and that would normally be a no-go but in this case there doesn't seem to be anything to replace it any time soon AFAIK.  All major browsers still support it so I'm keeping it for now in my CMS/WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).